# How to display preview of uploaded pdf in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

### I need to display pdf in the HTML page in laravel. I already upload the pdf from the form

```php
protected function create(array $data){

  $request = request();

  $profileImage = $request->file('RESUMES');
  $profileImageSaveAsName = time().'.'. $profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
   
  $upload_path = 'Cvs';
  $profile_image_url = $upload_path . $profileImageSaveAsName;
  $success = $profileImage->move($upload_path, $profileImageSaveAsName);
  

  return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'RESUMES' => $profile_image_url,
       
  ]);
  //dd($user);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your blade file you can embed the PDF file like so

```
<embed src="{{ asset('path-to-uploaded-file') }}" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" />
```

If you want to display the PDF file in the browser you can add a button that redirects to

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);

return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```

Comment: hai, how we can add dynamically here  mmabdelgawad

Comment: Add what dynamically ?

Comment: {{ asset('path-to-uploaded-file') }} actually here the corresponding file need to show . For example, I register with my resume in the register form the pdf will go to a folder. after I log in to  my dashboard, I need to display this pdf    mmabdelgawad

Comment: In your case after the user registers and redirected to their dashboard you will have the current authenticated user in the session so you can access the user CV using `auth()->user()->RESUMES` so you can do `{{ asset(auth()->user()->RESUMES) }}`

Comment: {{ asset(auth()->user()->RESUMES) }} not wroking folder Name is Cvs   mmabdelgawad